# When I try to select 1 row it selecting both rows into my database?

Tags: sql

```
select * from addcuust order by customer asc
```

This is my query. When  I run this query both rows selecting what should I do?
I just want 1 row at once.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` maybe?

Comment: You can try `LIMIT 1` a the first comment suggests or add  a proper `WHERE` clause to filter the result set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO returning single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456626/php-pdo-returning-single-row) (PDO) or [Single Result from Database by using mySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624509/single-result-from-database-by-using-mysqli) ()mysqli)

Comment: Next time, start by doing some research. I found _many_ posts about this straight away here on SO alone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * from addcuust order by customer asc limit 1
```

Comment: This doesn't really need an answer as it's a simple issue, well documented, and answered in the comments. However, if you're going to answer at least use code formatting and provide the correct syntax with appropriate matching `"` etc