# Check if the time is more than 24h and show it

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, pdo

I have in my MSSQL database a column with datatype of `datetime` which contains some dates in this format `2021-01-11 19:58:04.277`.

This is a voting system, the idea is that the users can only vote once every 24 hours.

Every time they vote this table is updated with a new record and a new date is added with the corresponding user.

I want to display a message that says how many hours left to place the next vote.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
 /**
 * Get Votes Time
 * 
 */
public function getVoteRemainingTime($account) {
    date_default_timezone_get();
    $currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = "SELECT VoteDate FROM dbo.vote WHERE Account = :account ORDER BY logid DESC";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':account' => $account)); 
    $voteDate = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $timeLeftVote = strtotime($currentTime) - strtotime($voteDate->VoteDate);

    if($timeLeftVote > 86400) {
        return '<strong>Vote Available!</strong>';
    } else {
        return $timeLeftVote;
    }

}
```

But it is displaying the wrong information. What I am doing wrong? I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: What does _...it is displaying the wrong information ..._ mean?

Answer (score 0):

you need declare format parameter of the `date()` like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

```
date_default_timezone_get();
$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$timeLeftVote = strtotime($currentTime) - strtotime('2021-01-11 19:58:04.277');
if($timeLeftVote > 86400){
    echo 'Vote available';
}else{
    echo $timeLeftVote;
}
```

Comment: It is still returning the incorrect value.

Comment: maybe because when you get VoteDate its not call only one data, try use `LIMIT 1` after `ORDER BY logid DESC`

Comment: I've changed it to: `"SELECT TOP 1 VoteDate FROM dbo.vote WHERE Account = :account ORDER BY VoteDate DESC"` In order to get the last vote date that was inserted in the db. but still same problem

Comment: you can tell me the result if you `echo $voteDate->VoteDate` ?

Comment: By doing `echo $voteDate->VoteDate` this is the output `2021-01-11 19:58:04.277`. This value is stored in the MSSQL.

Comment: maybe the problem is when you call `$voteDate->VoteDate` , if you only input `2021-01-11 19:58:04.277`  to my code its work

Comment: Yeah, that would be a static time. I need to fetch it from db to check the last vote the user did.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456626/php-pdo-returning-single-row

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with dates? I am returning the correct date from my db.

Comment: whats the meaning `It is still returning the incorrect value.` ? its always returning `else` condition ? or something else?

Comment: i dont know your code to get data from database is okay if i try at my local the only problem if i use `$currentTime = date('');` , but if use `$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` its work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT VoteDate FROM dbo.vote`

Can you do the calculation on the time difference at source in the database using

```
SELECT VoteDate, DATEDIFF(HOUR, VoteDate, GETDATE()) as HourDifference from dbo.vote
```

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot check your database query, I only checked the rest of the code and it seems to work (as Fikri F mentioned in the comments of this post) if I replace `$voteDate->VoteDate` by a static date.

So please provide more information. You could output the current time and the previous vote time from the database as strings, and for both dates as well the result of strtotime, and in the end the result of the method. Then please explain, what the wrong behaviour is. By this, we can narrow down the problem either to the DB query or to the PHP code.
(I would write this as a comment, but I have not enough reputation.)

Comment: Thanks for your time, I already fixed the problem.